# How to mathematically describe a whether an edge belongs to a geometric face

Tags: geometry, surfaces

No, it is not a human face. But rather, how can we mathematically describe if an edge, belongs to a face of a piece of geometry?

For example, let's say that you have a square within a square:

[image]

How would you be able to describe that the edges displayed belong to the outer square instead of the inner square?

Edit:
This problem is assuming that the inner square is a hole.

Also, I am only dealing in 2D space.

This is only a simplification of an overall problem. I am currently working on an alvorithm that will be able to take a list of lines, nodes (or vertices), and arcs and convert them into a data structure that is recognizable to GMSH. I have my own line, arc, and node list and I need to convert it into a GModel (for those who are famalier with gmsh, I am essentially creating a .geo file using the c++ source directly).

The format is that I need to specify all of the nodes in the gmodel. The gmsh equilivant to a node is a Gvertex. Then, to create the lines, I need to specify which Gvertex is associated with the gline. This part will be relatively easy.

The hard part is specifing the GFace. Basically, a GFace is a collection of Glines. But the challenge is is how to specify or how to know which Gline belongs to which face.

For example, say we have 2 squares, how can you identify line 1 belongs to square 1 or square 2?

In this example, how can you identify that the outer square is the actual face verses the inner square which is a hole? And how can you know that the edges belong to that face?

Again, this is a simplification. The answer would need to apply to any geometry.

Here is a link to a picture with a more complicated geometry. I think that the example that I gave was an over simplification:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pga7k.jpg

Edit 2:

Please forgive me. I am still developing my math terms and language. I am mostly a programmer. I will do my best to communicate my ideas to the users on the forum. Please though, if there is additional data that I need to clarify or need to say, let me know and I will happily edit this thread.

My geometry is composed of vertices which is a double of real numbers (x, y). This is only in 2-D. I am not doing anything with imaginary numbers or utilizing other graphs. This is 2-D Euclidean space. These vertices are stored in an array (or list or vector or whatever). There is no particular order to how the vertices are stored.

An edge is a pair of indices that is obtained from the vertex list. Ex. (2, 5) means that an edge is created between the 2nd and 5th node. For this, I consider arcs the same as edges but with information such as the arc angle, radius, and center of the arc.

Also, the edge list is in no particular order.

Basically, I need to generate a list of faces. A face will be defined by line loops which are an array of the edges that compose the face. The 0th index will be the outer most line. If there are any holes in the domain, then the proceeding indices in the array will be the holes. For the example of the square: lineLoop[0] = {1, 2, 3, 4}. The 1 is the first edge and the 2 is the second edge. (I didn't label the edges wih numbers but the numbering of the edges can start from any point as long as it is a counter clockwise direction). And lineLoop[1] = {5, 6, 7, 8}. At this point, lineLoop is able to describe the face effectively.

Comment: The answer will depend on how the vertices and edges are described in the first place. If you're using coordinates in the plane you'll want to think about convex hulls.

Comment: If the inner square is a hole then there is just a single face (which has a hole). So the edge necessarily belongs to it. How are your edges and faces represented? If they are sets of points, then $e\subset F$ can be one way to say that the edge $e$ belongs to the face $F$.

Comment: @M.Winter Yes it is a single face. I am attempting to code an algorithm that can create a plane on a face. From the programming standpoint, a hole and a face are the same. On my end, I do know that e belongs to F. But coding wise, this doesn't help very much

Comment: @philm It would help if you give the *exact* way you represent faces and edges. Otherwise there is little to help here. What does it mean to "create a plane on a face"?

Comment: @M.Winter I updated the OP to describe a little bit more. Basically, a face is represented by a collection of lines. To specify a face, I need to create a plane. I can create the plane and specify what collection of lines are holes. I apologize for any confusion

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you have vertices and edges and you want to extract the information what faces exist and what edges belong to which face? Or do you already know what faces exist, you got a face list or something? Can we assume that there is no unbounded face? Can we assume that any edge belongs to exactly one face and that any vertex is incident to exactly two edges?

Comment: Help us. Be explicit. What data do you have as inputs? What do you want as an output? Don't tell us in terms of data structures for packages we may not know --- we're mostly math folks, not GMSH programmers -- tell us in mathematical terms, as in "A point is a triple (x, y, z) of real numbers; my points are stored in an array $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_n$; An edge is a pair of indices $(p, k)$, so that $(2, 5)$ indicates an edge between point $P_2$ and $P_5$, ..." If you can't do that, then we probably can't help you.

Comment: @M.Winter This algorthim will be for arbitary geometry. I posted a link to a picture with more complex geometry. I do not have a list of faces. I have a list of edges (includes lines and arcs) and vertices. I need to create the face list for the entire geometry piece. The edges and vertices will not be in any particular order. It is required though that there are no open contours. All edges must be in a closed contour to make a face.  There are no unbounded face but an edge can belong to 1 or more faces like the image above.

Comment: @JohnHughes Ok, I have updated the thread to describe in more detail. Please let me know if there is anything additional that I can add in (As a side not, how are you able to make the P Italics and create the subscripts?) If I can make my description more into math language, please let me know so that I am able to cleary communication with the math community.

Comment: Your updated link is not accessible (at least not to me).

Comment: Re formatting: if you type `$a_i$`, it'll appear as $a_i$. Dollar signs switch to math mode; within math mode, `_` indicates subscripts; `^` indicates superscripts. If you need grouping, use `{}`, as in `$P_{i,j}$`, which gives $P_{i,j}$. In general, much of the math-formatting language "LaTeX" is supported in MSE; there are good tutorials, but I don't have a link for any of them offhand. Perhaps someone else will jump in here.

Comment: @philm Your link is indeed dead. Until now I have no clear idea how to extract the information whether a specific edge loop surrounds a face or hole. How should we know?

Comment: @M.Winter  Link is up. Please focus on the geometry lines, the other lines are for flux, ignore those guys

Comment: @JohnHughes Link is up. Please focus on the geometry lines, the other lines are for flux, ignore those guys

Comment: Someone else will have to focus on that. If you can't take the time to draw a clear picture of a typical input (or to describe it clearly), and to give a clear formulation of the output you want, then I'm not interested in trying to guess what your unclear one means.

Comment: Your recent edit shows that the problem you want to solve is MUCH HARDER than the one you originally asked. I doubt there's an algorithm that can be easily described in an answer on this site. You probably need to start with a good book on computational geometry.

Comment: @EthanBolker Indeed, I am starting to think the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Here's a solution, as far as one is possible. It makes two assumptions:

1. For each edge $ (a, b) $, there's exactly one other edge whose start or end point is $a$; that other edge's other endpoint is *not* $b$. So if you have edge $(2, 5)$, then there's an edge like $(2, 4)$ or $(17, 2)$ as well. The same goes for the vertex $b$.
2. The number of edges is finite.

OK, here goes.

STEP 1.

TL; DR: under the equivalence relation defined by "neighbor", find all equivalence classes, and organize each into a chain using "other".

We're going to form a list of chains (a "chain" being a sequence of (edge, vertex) pairs, where the vertex is one of the two vertices of the edge). I'll use the function $other$ which consumes an edge and a vertex of that edge, and returns the other vertex of the edge, so that $other( (2, 5), 2) = 5$ and $other((2, 5), 5) = 2$. I'll also use $neighbor( (a, b), b)$, which returns the unique edge $(b, c)$ or $(c, b)$ that shares vertex $b$ but for which $c \ne a$. Both "other" and "neighbor" can be implemented by a hashdictionary, for instance, using a single pass through the data.

Init: make the chain list empty; set $i$ to $0$.

While edge list is not empty:
   Create a new empty chain $C$. Remove from the edge list the first edge,  call it $(a, b)$. Set done = false. Place $( (a, b), b)$ into the chain $C$.

while not done:

- Let $(e, v)$ be the last item in $C$, and let $e' = neighbor(e, v)$. Let $d = other(e', v)$.
- If d = a, then set done = true, and insert $C$ into the chain list.

---

When you're done, you'll have a list $L$ of chains. For each chain, you can ignore the edges and just read off the vertices, and these will be the "faces" that you're looking for.

STEP 2:

Now you have to decide which are "faces" and which are "holes".

Unfortunately, from the data given, this cannot be determined. For instance, in the following diagram , there are three chains, which form concentric squares. On the left, the innermost chain bounds an orange square and the outer two together bound a blue ring-shaped face. But on the right, the outer one bounds a blue square, while the inner two bound a ring-shaped orange face. (The blue outer square shows through the hole in the inner ring). 
[image]

Perhaps you meant to include some constraint on whether faces can overlap (as they do in the right-hand example). But without that information (which is not part of the input or output you described), it's hopeless, as this example shows.

Comment: You know, your answer is sounding similiar to the Depth-first seach (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) I am currently looking into utilizing this idea to create the list of contours and from there, a list of faces.

Comment: It's exactly DFS, applied to the graph where the nodes are your edges and the graph-edges are between any two nodes (i.e., geometric edges) that share a geometric  vertex.

Comment: By the way, assuming that you want to treat edges like borders of countries, and that countries cannot overlap (like the ones in my second example do), the thing you want to use to represent your data is a "rotation system" or "young system"; from such a thing, it's straightforward to read off the "countries" of the graph (i.e., the faces), although if holes are allowed (as in the white and blue countries of the left-hand example), things are messier.

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking that I can get a list of all of the closed contours within the graph and from there detemine if they are holes or not. If a I have 2 closed contours, then I can check if a third lies in the domain and if so, that third one is "hole"

Comment: Truthfully, though, I think I need to do some more research before I post on this topic again. Maybe I will have a more clear idea within a few days or what.

Comment: It's probably not quite as simple as that. There's a 1929 paper by J.W. Alexander in the Proc. Nat'l Ada. Sci. that has a so-called "innermost circle" argument that might be slightly relevant, or at least inspire some ideas. But I believe you're right: more research, and more input-output examples will help clarify your thinking.

Answer (score 1):

There is no intrinsic difference between the edges. What I mean is that the answer completely depends on the ambient space where this manifold with boundary lies.

For example, if this space lies in $\mathbb R^2$ (what you probably had in mind), then yes, you can tell which square is "inner" and which is "outer" since the whole shape will divide the plane in two connected components, "inner" and "outer", and we can decide which is which since the "inner" component is simply connected, while the "outer" is not.

On the other side, we might not be in $\mathbb R^2$, for example this space might be embedded in sphere $S^2$. You can easily imagine something like equatorial belt, there is absolutely no way to decide what is "in" and what is "out", because the two connected components are identical.

Perhaps even more transparent way to see this is if we embed this space in $\mathbb R^3$ as a strip. Then there is only "outside" of the strip, i.e. only one connected component. You can easily imagine continuous transformation of this strip inside $\mathbb R^3$ which switches the edges (like turning socks inside out, just this sock is with a hole in it).

The point is, if you want me to give an answer, first tell me how this shape is embedded in some ambient space and depending on that, I will tell you what is in and what is out.

Comment: In addition: The definition of "face" is also quite important. For instance, is a face always simply-connected?

Comment: @gebruiker I guess a face in this example is anything that is a solid. For example, the hole is not a face because there is nothingness or just air. If we extruded and printed this object, then the outer square would be filled.

Comment: @ennar Yes, I am only working in the 2D space right now. Nothing fancy